# Android NDK (Sockets) - recvfrom() sets sockaddr *from NULL (can't get IP of sender)

Tags: android, sockets, networking, android-ndk

When I call `recvfrom` using the Android NDK, I get `NULL` returned to my `sockaddr_in` `from`. This same exact code works fine on my desktop environment, but not on the device.

```
int MyClass::ReceiveData(char *buffer, int bufferLength)
{
    int numBytes = 0;
    struct sockaddr_in from;
    socklen_t fromLength = sizeof(struct sockaddr_in);
    numBytes = recvfrom(mConnectionSocket,
                        buffer,
                        bufferLength,
                        0,
                        (struct sockaddr *)&from,
                        &fromLength);
    if (numBytes == -1)
        perror("recvfrom");

    int fromAddress = ntohl(from.sin_addr.s_addr);

    return fromAddress;
}
```

Anybody have any ideas?

Comment: Are you packaging the app correctly to include the so file?  When you say Desktop you mean Emulator...?

Comment: No, not emulator, I built a program that runs in the command line on my computer and uses the same exact code. It gets the correct IP address in 'from' on my computer, but for some reason it won't on an Android device.
Somebody else had the same issue awhile back, but nobody mentioned a fix: http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/6c380cadccca079b

Comment: Can you post your header code to see which *.h your using and your make file for android NDK?

Comment: Just to make sure I post the right stuff, what header code are you asking for?

Comment: What are all the *.h files the above code is using?

Comment: Not all of these may pertain specifically to this section, but these are being included:
`#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <ifaddrs.h>`

Answer (score 0):

> I get NULL returned to my sockaddr_in 'from'

That's not possible with that code. `from` isn't a pointer that can become `NULL`. More probably your sockaddr_in structure named by `from` is getting *zeroed.* Which would be caused by using this on a TCP socket. If this is TCP you should be calling `getpeername()` on the socket to get the peer address.

Comment: Apologies for mistakenly referring to 0 as NULL (although considering this is C++, NULL is defined as 0, so they're technically the same thing). Regardless, the issue remains. The result in 'from' is 0. This definitely isn't being used on a TCP socket either. As I said, it works fine when this code is part of a command line program, it just doesn't work when its on the device.